# .synctex.gz(busy)

Tags: errors, miktex

I am trying to compile a tex file using `texstudio`. All settings/configuration seem to be OK. I am using a local repository with all packages I need.

However, when attempting at compiling I get this error message:

> Syntax Error: Top-level pages object is wrong type (null)
>   Process exited with error(s)

Also, when looking at files that get created when compiling the tex document I noticed the presence of `.synctex.gz(busy)`.

Any help on this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

This often happens after a crash of the editor. In such a case simply close the editor, delete the sync file `<filename>.synctex.gz` and restart the editor. The file is in the same directory as your main TeX source file.

Comment: When searching for a solution to a bit similar problem, I came across your answer. So, I wonder if you could help me with [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438994/2288). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a corrupted pdf file (image to be included in the document). It now works fine, thanks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/88704)

Comment: @Zarko Well, it seems to be the solution in this case (fixing the corrupt pdf image).

Comment: +1 for an answer that helped someone else (me). LaTeX can get pretty annoying when it gives out these elusive error messages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a TikZ line

```
\node (l) {$0$}
```

that was simply missing the semicolon at the end:

```
\node (l) {$0$};
```