# Why does TeXstudio go into endless compilation in case of errors?

Tags: texstudio, windows, texlive-2018

A few years ago, when encountering errors with my code, TeXstudio stopped and produced a log file.

However, for a while, I have been suffering from stucking with endless compilation in case of errors, which forces me to stop compilation and use arara instead in order to recognize where the problem is.

It shows me that in the messages panel below that the document is being compiled (i.e. the message `Process started...` shows up), while I feel that it does nothing heavy by checking the CPU activity.

So, what are the possible reasons that make TeXstudio do so, knowing that the version of TeXstudio is 2.12.8 and that of TeX Live is 2018 (up-to-date) running on Windows 10 v1803?

Comment: Go to the editor preferences, what is selected for pdflatex? Seems you are in nteractive mode.

Comment: @Johannes_B `lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape %.tex` and the same preferences for `pdflatex`.

Comment: TeXstudio allows up to five compilation repetitions in its configuration.

Comment: @djnavas I don't know exactly what it does during that time, but it seems that it does nothing while showing me that it is compiling the document, which makes me click on the `Stop  Compile` button.

Comment: It can be doing many things. For instance, downloading a needed file. Looking for fonts. Wating for a machine process to finish, like reading a file or locating an alternative file. In those cases I have seeing lualatex at 0% cpu load but a process was under way.

Comment: It should be something like `lualatex --shell-escape  -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` The `nonstopmode` is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Herbert's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438994/why-does-texstudio-go-into-endless-compilation-in-case-of-errors?noredirect=1#comment1102316_438994), the issue is solved by considering the option `-interaction=nonstopmode` in the command.